# Buttons in Cell not clickable IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

UITableViewCell with a few buttons on it, On IOS 8.4 buttons clickable (Able to get tap event), In IOS 9 Unable to get tap event.

Did any one notice this?

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code. Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for this, I think this bug was at the past already at IOS 6.. any way you should add this to your UITableViewCell:

```
self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But this was because I've added the views to the cell itself, instead of I'ts contentView.

Comment: your solution will work only if you added buttons to cell directly not to `contentView` that not right

Answer (score 0):

To enable a button that is on the content view, simply enable the button
`subview.Btn.userInteractionEnabled = true`

You might also want to bring the subview to front prior to this
`cell.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(subview)`